# Remove buttons from Gitlab interface

Tags: gitlab

Is there a way to remove the buttons for `Add Changelog`, `Add license`, `Add Contribution guide`, `Add kubernetes cluster`, and `set up CI/CD`, as well as the banner for `Auto DevOps (Beta)` from a project page?

These are all features that are not necessary for me at the moment and it would be a much cleaner interface without the buttons & banner. There is an image below to show what  I mean.

Version GitLab 10.6.0-ee

[image: Image showing the offending buttons]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This process worked for me on GitLab 10.8.14 to remove the auto devops message from annoying everyone.

```
sudo gitlab-rails console

Feature.get(:auto_devops_banner_disabled).enable => true

exit

sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
```

Comment: That works for the devops banner! Nice one. How about the rest of the buttons, are they configurable from the same place?

Comment: There is an open issue asking for this feature, see https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/45815

Comment: I'm getting an error SyntaxError ((irb):5: syntax error, unexpected =>

Comment: Here ist the link to the [gitlab-docu auto-devops-banner](https://docs.gitlab.com/13.7/ee/topics/autodevops/customize.html#auto-devops-banner)

Comment: Above link is broken, now use https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/autodevops/customize.html#auto-devops-banner Another one is https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/autodevops/index.html#enable-or-disable-auto-devops

Answer (score -1):

You can remove the Auto DevOps part by clicking on the 'X' button. 
The other parts at the top, you can set up the documentation files and a kubernetes cluster.

Comment: That only removes it temporarily. I don't want to create those files or the Kubernetes cluster, which is why I want the buttons removed.